# php pdo code to echo multiple values inside one textbox

Tags: php, pdo

field name - receipt no,coupon,schemename

i create a form which has receipt no textbox.

**Need to search all couponno based on entered receipt no. and need to echo all coupon no in comma seprated format inside textbox.**

for ex-- in my database...foll. data are present..

receipt no  coupon  schemename

701           511      one month

701           512      one month

701           513      one month

**Now I need is select all coupon of 701 and echo inside coupon textbox .**

**for ex - 511,512,513 echo all couponno in one textbox.**

plz help me how to do this

```
<?php
$scheme = "";$book = "";$coup = "";$amou = "";$rec = "";$cit = "";
 $db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=circulation_scheme_prepaid','root','');
if($_POST && isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $result=$db->prepare('SELECT scheme_name,coupon, FROM scheme_master WHERE receipt_no=:receipt_no');
    $result->bindParam(':receipt_no',$_POST['receipt_no']);
    $result->execute();
    foreach($result as $row){    
        $scheme =  $row['scheme_name'];         
        $coup =  $row['coupon'];  
    }
}?>

**receipt no textbox** - I get input from this textbox
<input type="text" name="receipt_no"  />
```

I Need to echo all coupon no inside below textbox.

coupon textbox - `<input type="text" name="coupon" value="<?php echo $coup;?>" class="field size2" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
<?php
$scheme = "";$book = "";$coup = "";$amou = "";$rec = "";$cit = "";
 $db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=circulation_scheme_prepaid','root','');
if($_POST && isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $result=$db->prepare('SELECT scheme_name,coupon, FROM scheme_master WHERE receipt_no=:receipt_no');
    $result->bindParam(':receipt_no',$_POST['receipt_no']);
    $result->execute();
    $data = $result->fetchAll();
    $coupons = array();

    foreach($data as $row){    
        $coupons[] = $row['coupon']; 
    }
}?>

<input type="text"  value="<?php echo implode(',', $coupons); ?>"/>
```

Comment: but this shows me an error  Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp\www\prepaidnew\customer_entry.php on  <input type="text"  value="<?php echo implode(',', $coupons); ?>"/>

Comment: and also suggest how to insert this textbox values in insert query to insert coupon textbox value in another table..in

Comment: below is my insert query  $coupon = $_POST['coupon'];     $insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO city_master (coupon) VALUES (:coupon)", 
       array(':coupon'=>$coupon));

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$scheme = "";$book = "";$coup = "";$amou = "";$rec = "";$cit = "";
$db=new     PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=circulation_scheme_prepaid','root','');
if($_POST && isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $result=$db->prepare('SELECT coupon FROM scheme_master WHERE receipt_no=:receipt_no');
    $result->bindParam(':receipt_no',$_POST['receipt_no']);
    $result->execute();
    $data = $result->fetchAll();

    foreach($data as $row) {    
       $value[] = end($row); 
     }
     $coupons = implode(',', $value);
}?>


<input type="text"  value="<?php echo $coupons ?>"/>
```

Comment: Not display any value inside textbox this display only array inside textbox.

Comment: please try $coupons be a variable not an array